# How to unload a .NET assembly reference in IronPython

Tags: python, .net, ironpython, python.net

After loading a reference to an assembly with something like:

```
import clr
clr.AddRferenceToFileAndPath(r'C:\foo.dll')
```

How can I unload the assembly again?

Why would anyone ever want to do this? Because I'm recompiling `foo.dll` and want to reload it, but the compiler is giving me a fuss, since IronPython is allready accessing `foo.dll`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

.NET itself doesn't support unloading just a single assembly. Instead, you need to unload a whole `AppDomain`. I don't know exactly how IronPython works with `AppDomain`s, but that's the normal .NET way of doing things. (Load the assembly into a new `AppDomain`, use it, discard the `AppDomain`, create a new `AppDomain` with the new version of the file etc.)